# Unable to access PHP array in javascript, javascript object initialized to array ends up empty in chrome developer tools

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

I'm trying to get a JSON from PHP array so I can overlay the JSON on to a google charts geochart. So I am trying to get this working by using this simple code in test.php file

```
<?php 
  include("conn.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.onload = function (){
    var jsonObj = <?php echo json_encode($rowarr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); ?>;
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, '\n');
    console.log(jsonString);
  };

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The conn.php file returns an array like so

```
{"Auckland":37616,"Wellington":35357,"Christchurch":29818}
```

But in the chrome developer tools I see that this code appears as

```
document.onload = function (){
var jsonObj = ;
    // Chrome error here -> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, '\n');
```

The jsonObj variable is empty, when there should be something in it.

On the CDT console I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

at line 11 in this test.php file

Comment: please post the content of conn.php.

Comment: Did you make sure `$rowarr` is not empty and accessible?

Comment: @Biotox - I have checked that file in the browser with print_r($rowarr) and it outputs the correct values like I wrote above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this kind of scenario yesterday.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.onload = function (){
    var jsonObj = <?php echo json_encode($rowarr); ?>;
    var jsonString = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
    console.log(jsonString);
  };

</script>
```

Comment: Where do you wanna store the parsed JSON? in a grid?

Comment: I'm trying to get the JSON into a google chart datatable to overlay on a geo chart. I used your solution and I get this in jsonObj - `{"Auckland":37616,"Wellington":35357,"Christchurch":29818}`. However nothing gets logged to console.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome somtimes just doesn't show processable arrays and XMLs properly but they are exist.
my advise: just dont test your codes on chrome before getting actual results on other Browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that $rowarr doesn't contain what you think it contains.  Maybe try logging it first....

```
console.log("$rowarr");
```

Comment: I have checked this. It does contain what it needs to contain. However I had to do this to get it to display in the source code, console.log("<?php print_r($rowarr) ?>");. There was an 

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in console, but the  resources tab showed the source with the expected array.

Answer (score -1):

You're along the right lines.

First of all, you can get rid of the enclosing document.onload as it's pointless.

Secondly, here's the amended code:

```
var jsonStringified = <?php echo json_encode($rowarr); ?>,
    jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonStringified);

console.log(jsonObject);
```